# What book did Luke Skywalker resurrect himself in?

Tags: star-wars

I need to know if Luke Skywalker used the Force to bring himself back from the dead and what book it was in. I think it was "The Courtship of Princess Leia", but I'm not sure. I would also like to know (if it's true) if it is specified, if the Force itself brought Luke back to life or if it was a direct application of Luke himself.

Comment: There's no mention of this in the book's [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Courtship_of_Princess_Leia) -- which of course proves nothing.

Comment: I can say for sure he did not bring himself back from the dead in "The Courtship of Princess Leia", nor in any of the other books I've read, and I've read quite a bit of the EU novels

Comment: Well, not from the _dead_ exactly, but he was getting pretty close.  The surrounding environment _did_ give him force energy in some way.

Comment: @X-Zero - being seriously injured is hardly dead. And he has been 'seriously injured' in multiple books

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, Luke managed to '[become one with the force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Ghost)' and came back to talk to the living in [Star Wars: Legacy 3: Broken, Part 3](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_Legacy_3%3a_Broken,_Part_3).  He may have done so at other times, but that's the first reference to it that I recall. Not sure if it counts as a book, tho.. It was a comic book series.

Regardless, that's acting as a Force Ghost; if you are looking for resurrection, I don't recall him doing that.  The whole Force Ghost thing was also ret-conned after the prequels came out, so YMMV with what it means.  Initially, it was something all of the good/redeemed Jedi could do; later it became a rediscovered technique.  In '[The New Rebellion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Rebellion)' Luke prepares himself for being killed by engaging in the needed technique in advance.

Comment: So many slang terms I dont know. Ret-conned, YMMV.

Comment: Ret-conned means 'retroactive continuity', essentially explaining previously incompatible facts with new information.
YMMV means "your mileage may vary" - essentially meaning "take whatever from this"

Answer (score 3):

In the "The Courtship of Princess Leia" he didn't technically bring *himself* back to life, however, he was very seriously injured and near death but was healed via the Force.